# CSS Header Image (Resizing Issue)

Tags: html, css, image, header, resize

I'm stuck with the CSS of following HTML link and want to expand the `height` of header image so I can adjust larger with it, but when I play with the CSS of the `.header` & `.logo` classes it expands the navigation bar also, I just really need to expand the `height` of the header image to have larger height logo into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking your html source seems you can have different solutions. Problem is with your html... You have

```
  <div class="navigation">
```

inside

```
  <div class="container">
```

Ans : get navigation div out of container div. Then changing the height of `container div` would be the best and not affect the height of your links.

**Why you are getting problem :** your header div is containing links inside it. That is why changing the height of header is not good (It simply changes the overall height of this div).

**Update :** Reply to your first comment on my answer

```
  <div class="inner">
     <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo Start -->
            <div class="five columns left">
                <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Logo End -->
            <div class="eleven columns right">
                <!-- Top Links Start -->
                <ul class="top-links">
                    <li>
                        <h4 class="colr">Search Music</h4>
                        <div id="search-box">
                            <input name="" value="Enter any keyword"
                            onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter any keyword') {this.value='';}"
                            onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value='Enter any keyword';}" type="text" class="bar" />
                            <button>Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('login-box')" class="colr">LOG IN</a>
                        <div id="login-box">
                            <h4 class="white backcolr">User Login <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.hide('login-box')" class="closeit">&nbsp;</a></h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <input name="" value="yourname@email.com"
                                    onfocus="if(this.value=='yourname@email.com') {this.value='';}"
                                    onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value='yourname@email.com';}"   type="text" class="bar" />
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input name="" value="password"
                                    onfocus="if(this.value=='password') {this.value='';}"
                                    onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value='password';}"   type="password" class="bar" />
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="left" />
                                    <p>Remember me</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="right">Forget Password?</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button class="backcolrhover">Login</button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Top Links End -->
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Container End -->


        <!-- Navigation Start -->
            <div class="navigation">
                <div id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu">
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Albums</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="albums.html">Albums</a></li>
                                <li><a href="album-detail.html">Album Detail</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="blog-detail.html">Blog Detail</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="gallery-two-column.html">Gallery - Two Column</a></li>
                                <li><a href="gallery-three-column.html">Gallery - Three Column</a></li>
                                <li><a href="gallery-four-column.html">Gallery - Four Column</a></li>
                                <li><a href="gallery-slideshow.html">Gallery - Slide Show</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BUY THIS THEME</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Navigation End -->
        </div>
```

Then change your css and see the results

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100px; /* I have changed it 50px to 100px*/
    float:left;
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

Comment: I did this but still no luck :( , can you please give me code hint so i can exactly get into it ?? Im newbie in website development , may be i'm doing wrong :(

Comment: @Alex. Check out now. Hope you would be able to fix

Comment: Thanks Mate , i've done it while playing with different classes after implementing your trick :) you are awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your header height here :

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:148px;  <-----------Here
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 2px #000;
    background:url(../images/header.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

Edit: I just inspected with firebug, you are using multiple classes and you've nested div's, your logo div lies here

`five columns left`

I guess you've picked this template and you are trying to edit it right?

Comment: yes exactly i got this template & trying to edit it , well i've already changed that value of #header , but instead of expanding height of header.gif , it has increased height of the space below navigation :( , can you please help , i'm newbie in this :( , check the demo link again & see it has effected wrong

Comment: @Alex it's actually very complicated to tell because the designer has used multiple classes, and if you chane a class it effects other containers too, I would suggest you to make 1 yourself